# Ethernet Cable Causing 404

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, wireless-extender

I use a wifi extender ([this one](https://express.google.com/u/0/product/12213583703474867832_15535662545758817530_6136318?mall=Rockies2&directCheckout=1&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=product_ads&utm_campaign=gsx&dclid=CMP0wrOn4tYCFVB7AQod0v8IYg)) because my physical location for my computer is right at the edge of the range my network card can connect within.  Up until about a month ago, it had been working fine (except for the occasional speed drop), in fact I was running an ethernet cable to the box to squeeze a little extra speed out.  I had it plugged into a surge protector though, and my hardware friend thought that moving it to a basic wall socket would help with me randomly losing 50% or more of my internet speed (ping time) randomly.  Which it did.  But now, anytime I use an ethernet cable to the box, any site that isn't Google or a from the engine registers as 404.  This includes the Steam Store, which is really weird.  I have no idea what's going on, and neither do any of my Google searches.

PS: I have moved it back to the power strip and tried that. I have updated the drivers on both my network card and the ones for the extender. I have run diagnostics, but Windows (10) thinks everything is fine.

Comment: It sounds like a local IP address is changing when you plug in the cable vs using it as a WiFi extender.  What happens if after you plug in and start getting the 404’s if the computer get shutdown and restarted?

Comment: Just tried.  Nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

A 404 implies an APPLICATION LEVEL problem (it means File not found on server - which means the server needs to be contacted and provide this information).

A 404 error is not a (client side) IP address problem or a cabling problem -and in fact this error rules out those possibilities.

If all sites are getting it, the traffic is being intercepted somewhere and the software doing it has problems.  This could be a transparent proxy or Antivirus software.   It could conceivably also be a DNS issue if you are not going to HTTPS sites.  This could be happening at your router or ISP as well.